# How can a computer found on traceroute show all ports closed?

Tags: ip, nmap, ports

I ran a traceroute on a website I'm connecting to and got the following output:

```
1  skyrouter (192.168.0.1)  3.989 ms  1.389 ms  1.916 ms
 2  * * *
 3  be397.pr2.thlon.isp.sky.com (2.120.11.8)  31.564 ms  40.750 ms  28.794 ms
 4  ae-3.r02.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (83.231.221.45)  26.772 ms  27.799 ms  27.415 ms
 5  ae-3.r24.londen12.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.4.23)  33.121 ms  27.261 ms  28.305 ms
 6  ae-6.r24.frnkge08.de.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.3.13)  37.456 ms  41.661 ms  59.803 ms
 7  ae-2.r02.frnkge04.de.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.5.53)  37.220 ms  41.979 ms  39.719 ms
 8  ve16-xe1-3-rt1-muc2.premium-datacenter.de (213.198.81.142)  42.982 ms  41.741 ms  40.887 ms
 9  104.28.20.80 (104.28.20.80)  41.024 ms  39.590 ms  38.321 ms
```

I nmapped the computer on the second hop and got this:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-18 15:14 GMT
Nmap scan report for ae-3.r02.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (83.231.221.45)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on ae-3.r02.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (83.231.221.45) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 28.04 seconds
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, but surely if I'm able to make a hop to a computer one port at least should be discoverable? If it is, what alternative methodology can I use to find out what the open port it is communicating through really is.

Comment: Beware: blindly `nmap`ing infrastructure you don't control **could** be regarded as breakin-attempt and might lead to unfavourable consequences.

Comment: @guntbert so could a lot of things :P. You're basically talking about looking at the doors of a house ;).

Comment: No, we are talking about **knocking** at **every door/window** of a house. But it was only a friendly warning :-)

Comment: Knocking on the door and window of every house would imply people can hear it. Most people don't hear an nmap.

Comment: But most major infrastructures do have netadmins who are automatically alerted when a not-so-stealthy scan of their systems is performed. It's not likely to get you in trouble, but it doe technically get dangerously close to violating the CFAA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the Nmap results, I have three remarks:

- you only scanned 1000 from 65000ish available ports (130000ish when you add together TCP and UDP)
- you might not be allowed to access any ports on that router. So called ACLs, access control lists, control which source might have access to a port or not wether it is open or closed.
- there might very well be no ports open. Routers are IP ([layer 3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) devices, often embedded and built solely for routing purposes. Ports on the other hand are on TCP and UDP, which are [layer 4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

As to your follow up question of „I can trace route it, there must be a port“:

What trace routing is is sending a packet to the final destination host over and over again, starting with a TTL (time to live) of 1 and increasing that TTL.

The specifications of IP say a router should inform the sender if instead of routing the packet further it was dropped due to a TTL of 0. (routers are to decrease the TTL on every hop by the number of seconds it took them to process, at least 1.) This is done in the form of an ICMP packet sent from the router to your machine and catches and correlated with the packet it sent out.

Hence, for you to be able to trace route the router, you do not need an open port. As it does send ICMP messages, it should however respond to an ICMP echo request and nmap is telling you that correctly (with “1 host up”).

Answer (score 0):

The firewall could only be configured to allow traffic to/from certain hosts over certain ports.  For instance, when I configure the local firewall on devices I manage, the use case is to not allow web browsing yet allow port 80 traffic to certain internal places.  So I allow port 80 to a defined list of IP addresses and block all other.  I also only allow incoming traffic from known good sources, so for all intents and purposes, other devices wouldn't see that as being available.

If I managed intermediate routing devices like these, I'd want to be sure that they're not getting swamped with traffic they aren't supposed to handle.

Comment: Ok, I've accepted this because it's an accurate answer. What I was interested in particularly, though, I guess, is how to discover how the intermediate computer is routing to the queried host and what port it's doing it via, which must be possible from my local computer if I am able to run a successful traceroute that routes via it.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I added an answer of my own, as I find this one misleading and borderline false as well as not accurate. It usually is a good measure to wait a day or two before accepting an answer, especially if you are not content with the answer. Even though you can undo accepts, questions without an accepted answers usually attract more answers than those with an accepted answer.